# How to show specific category products in cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, products, category-products

I would like to show specific category products in a cart page when one of its product from that category is added to the cart and also would like to show all those products in carousel. Can anyone please guide me on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your phtml file you can add this code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
          ->setData('category_id','$YourCategoryId')
          ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

And you can provide your category id with some condition and change phtml file for your diff, design.