# How to show a category's products in shopping cart

Tags: product, checkout, category, cart, magento2.3

**Magento version 2.3**

I want to show a particular category in shopping cart page using programming, instead of using backend widget settings.

I have tried to modify the following files with no luck:

`Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
```

which returns error, it says that block cannot set `type` attribute

[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlxABizZYZo)

`Magento_Checkout/templates/cart.phtml`

```
if ($block->getItemsCount()) {
    echo $block->getChildHtml('with-items');
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
          ->setData('category_id','$YourCategoryId')
          ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); 
} else {
    echo $block->getChildHtml('no-items');
}
```

returns error code 500

[source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141113/80197)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in your

Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<block type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" />
```

> Magento_Checkout/templates/cart.phtml:

```
$YourCategoryId = $this->getData("category_id");
if ($block->getItemsCount()) {
    echo $block->getChildHtml('with-items');
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
          ->setData('category_id',$YourCategoryId)
          ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); 
} else {
    echo $block->getChildHtml('no-items');
}
```

Comment: 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: catalog/product_list
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class catalog/product_list does not exist

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Same error, Block doesn't allow type and category_id, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to display the specific category wise products on Cart page,
you need to include following code

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml (Override the module as per your convinience)

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"  name="category.products.list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <arguments>                            
                        <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="number">3</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

**Note :**

1. In Above code we have reused the default product list template, you can Create the separate template for that and modify the code accordingly.
2. In Above code "3" is the category id, Change the category id as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi there, I actually wrote a similar code to yours. But I still tried your code just in case. I still get the same error. Class catalog/product_list does not exist AND Invalid block type: catalog/product_list

Comment: I think there is no catalog/product_list in layout folder, that's why it's causing this issue. But I am not sure.

Comment: An answer for another question said that I have to whitelist catalog/product_list, but there is no such settings in backend https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98084/80197

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a Wiget to add product list with a category on Shopping Cart this option without using any custom

[image]

**Update 2**
I follow your activity I got you are using Magento 2 CMS, but you are using Block type and code style of Magento 1. which this option you should use. 
**Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct** instead of **catalog\product_list**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
<action method="setToolbarBlockName">
     <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="number">[category id]</argument>
</action>
</block>
```

If you need to customer order product collection by own. You need to create new Block extends **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct** 
and custom **_getProductCollection** function.

**New Block XML**

```
<block class="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
         <argument name="category_id" xsi:type="number">[category id]</argument>
    </action>
 </block>
```

**Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProduct**

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        $this->_productCollection->setOrder('[attribute code]', 'desc');
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: I modified my question, I need to solve this programmatically, in order to achieve certain feature

Comment: Updated answer. You need to define Magento Version you have used.

Comment: What does this sentence means? "If you need to customer order product collection by own."

Comment: How do I create new block? in what folder? app/code, app/design?

Comment: You need to learn how to create block Magento 2 first.

Comment: That's helpful lol